# C++ Encrypting a sentence (char array) using an alternate alphabet (Possible Duplicate)

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption

I am having a bit of trouble with a part of a project I am working on.
I've been messing around with the code but I can't get it to work.
Basically, the project does the following:

1. Enter a word
2. Remove the duplicates
3. Store the modified word into an alternate alphabet
4. Use that alternate alphabet to encrypt a sentence

I am stuck on number 4.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void fixRepeats(char array[], int size);  //Function to remove duplicates
void fixSpaces(char array[], int size);  //Function to remove spaces
void copy(char array[], char array2[], int size);

int main()
{
    char word[25];
    char modWord[25];  //User inputted word without repeated letters
    char regAlpha[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char altAlpha[27];  //Alternate alphabet created from the word
    char sentence[100];
    int lenWord;  
    int lenModWord;  
    int lenAlpha = 27;
    int lenSent; 

    cout << "Please enter a single word: ";  //Get user input

    cin >> word;

    lenWord = strlen(word);  //Get length of word

    fixRepeats(word, lenWord);  //Function call from main
    fixSpaces(word, lenWord);  //Function call from main

    lenModWord = strlen(word);  //Get length of the modified word

    copy(word, modWord, lenModWord);  //Function call from main
    copy(modWord, altAlpha, lenModWord);  //Function call from main

    for (int i = 0; i < lenAlpha; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lenModWord; j++)
        {
            if (regAlpha[i] == altAlpha[j])
            {
                regAlpha[i++];
            }
        }

        altAlpha[lenModWord++] = regAlpha[i];
    }

    fixRepeats(altAlpha, lenAlpha);
    fixSpaces(altAlpha, lenAlpha);

    cout << "\nModified Word: " << word << endl;
    cout << "\nAlphabet------: " << regAlpha << endl;
    cout << "Encryption Key: " << altAlpha << endl;

    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    cout << "\nPlease enter a sentence: ";  //Get user input
    cin.get(sentence, 99, '\n');

    lenSent = strlen(sentence);

    //-------------------------------#4------------------------------------

    for (int i = 0; i < lenAlpha; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lenSent; j++)
        {
            if (altAlpha[i] == sentence[j])
            {
                sentence[j] = regAlpha[i]; 
            }
        }
    }

    //-------------------------------#4------------------------------------

    cout << "\nEncrypted message: " << sentence << endl;

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void copy(char array[], char array2[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array2[i] = array[i];
    }
}

void fixRepeats(char array[], int size)
{
    //Use nested loop to check each character
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= size; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] == array[j])  //Check for duplicates
            {
                array[j] = '\0';  //Change duplicate to a null char
            }
        }
    }
}

void fixSpaces(char array[], int size)
{
    //Use nested loop to check each character
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == '\0')  //Check for space or null char
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] != '\0')  //Check the next position
                {
                    swap(array[j], array[i]);  //Swap positions
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I marked my issue in the code with dashes and the #4.

The desired outcome is something like this:

```
Please enter a single word: HELLO

Modified Word: HELO

Alphabet------: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Encryption Key: HELOABCDFGIJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ

Please enter a sentence: HE IS HUMAN

Encrypted message: DA FS DUKHM
```

Another example using the same word is:

```
Please enter a sentence: COMPUTER SCIENCE

Encrypted message: LNKPUTAR SLFAMLA

Please enter a sentence: PLEASE HELP

Encrypted message: PJAHSA DAJP
```

When I run my code, it becomes something this:

```
Please enter a single word: HELLO

Modified Word: HELO

Alphabet------: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Encryption Key: HELOABCDFGIJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ

Please enter a sentence: HE IS HUMAN

Encrypted message: EO OS EUOEO
```

And:

```
Please enter a sentence: COMPUTER SCIENCE

Encrypted message: LHOPUTOR SLOOOLO

Please enter a sentence: PLEASE HELP

Encrypted message: PLOESO EOLP
```

Everything else is perfectly fine, it's just the encryption part that's wrong.
I am also aware that it's completely wrong (it's more of an attempt really).

Any suggestions on how to fix that single part (assuming that it can work for any word inputted)?

Thanks. And sorry for the lengthy post.

Comment: Should it be: `sentence[j] = regAlpha[i];` instead of `sentence[i] = regAlpha[i];`?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change that part (I copy & pasted this code before I changed it into that). In my real code, it's sentence[j] = regAlpha[i]. But it's still wrong anyway.

Comment: @J.F. In your `fixRepeats` function this loop: `for (int j = i + 1; j <= size; j++)` loop and the nested one looks like it accesses one past the end of your array on the last iteration.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Should I make it '<' instead of '<=' ?

Comment: @J.F. Yes, you should use `<`.  Anytime a loop is written using `<=`, it looks suspicious, and yours will access one element out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking using the target alphabet and then modifying using the wrong index, with the source alphabet.

This :

```
    if (altAlpha[i] == sentence[j])
    {
        sentence[i] = regAlpha[i];
    }
```

should be :

```
    if (regAlpha[i] == sentence[j])
    {
        sentence[j] = altAlpha[i]; 
        break; 
    }
```

The break is necessary to avoid encrypting some characters multiple times.

---

You also need to change the order of your loops to avoid encrypting some characters multiple times.  So this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < lenAlpha; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lenSent; j++)
```

becomes :

```
for (int j = 0; j < lenSent; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lenAlpha; i++)
```

---

Stitching it together, your `for` loops should look like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < lenSent; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lenAlpha; i++)
    {
        if (regAlpha[i] == sentence[j])
        {
            sentence[j] = altAlpha[i]; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, read that wrong. Sorry about that. The program did output correctly. Thank you so much & sorry for that little misread!

Comment: Oh wait. When I run the code, if I type the word HUMAN, it encrypts to DUKDM. In other words, the letters H and A are becoming D when encrypted. H becoming D is correct but A is supposed to become H, not D. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Yes, you have to add a `break;`.  See above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change letters in sentence to altAlpha elements but you need to use the position index of the letter from lenAlpha.

So, you should modify this part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lenAlpha; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lenSent; j++)
    {
        if (altAlpha[i] == sentence[j])
        {
            sentence[j] = regAlpha[i]; 
        }
    }
}
```

like

```
for (int i = 0; i < lenSent; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lenAlpha; j++)
    {
        if (sentence[i] == regAlpha[j])
        {
            sentence[i] = altAlpha[j]; 
        }
    }
}
```